# Loop with inner loop and split

Tags: t-sql

I have records like this in a table called "Entry":

```
TABLE: Entry

ID      Tags
---     ------------------------------------------------------ 
1       Coffee, Tea, Cake, BBQ
2       Soda, Lemonade
```

...etc.

TABLE: Tags

```
ID      TagName
----    -----------
1       Coffee
2       Tea
3       Soda
...

TABLE: TagEntry

ID    TAGID    ENTRYID
---   -----    -------
1     1        1
2     2        1
3     3        2
....
```

I need to loop through each record in the entire table for Entry, then for each row loop the comma delimited tags because I need to split each tag then do a Tag lookup based on tag name to grab the TagID, and then ultimately insert TagID, EntryID in a bridge table called TagEntry for each comma delimited tag

Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;with entry as
(
    select 1 id, 'Coffee, Tea, Cake, BBQ' tags
    Union all
    select 2, 'Soda, Lemonade'
), tags as
(
    select 1 id,'Coffee' TagName union all
    select 2,'Tea' union all
    select 3,'Soda'
), entryxml as
(
    SELECT id, ltrim(rtrim(r.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'))) as Item from (
    select id, CONVERT(XML, N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(tags,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>') as XmlString
    from entry ) x
    CROSS APPLY x.XmlString.nodes('//root/r') AS RECORDS(r)
)
select e.id EntryId, t.id TagId from entryxml e
inner join tags t on e.Item = t.TagName
```

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, it is splitting your entry values into rows, try `select * from entryxml` and see results

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will split your Entry table, for joining to the others:

```
with raw as (
  select * from ( values 
    (1, 'Coffee, Tea, Cake, BBQ'),
    (2, 'Soda, Lemonade')
  ) Entry(ID,Tags)
)
, data as (
    select ID, Tag = convert(varchar(255),' '), Tags, [Length] = len(Tags) from raw
  union all
    select 
      ID   = ID,
      Tag  = case when charindex(',',Tags) = 0 then Tags else convert(varchar(255), substring(Tags, 1, charindex(',',Tags)-1) ) end,
      Tags = substring(Tags, charindex(',',Tags)+1, 255),
      [Length] = [Length] - case when charindex(',',Tags) = 0 then len(Tags) else charindex(',',Tags) end
    from data
    where [Length] > 0
) 
select ID, Tag = ltrim(Tag)
from data
where Tag <> ''
```

and returns this for the given input:

```
ID          Tag
----------- ------------
2           Soda
2           Lemonade
1           Coffee
1           Tea
1           Cake
1           BBQ
```